# Vue.js How do you separate client and server sides?

Tags: node.js, api, express, vue.js

All of the side projects I worked before used webpack to build React app and did

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/index.html');
});
```

in server.js using Express to render the client/server on the same port.

But I recently learned that the usual practice is to separate client/server. So I was going to host the client on S3 and host the server on EC2 to handle any API calls. I heard you can do so by using proxy settings in Vue to redirect any API calls to the actual backend server.

This leads to my question:

If I do the above (front-end on S3, API calls on EC2), how do you handle client-side settings (ex.caching) when this is usually done by Express, which sits in back-end server?

Am I misunderstanding how I should seprate client/server?? Please enlighten me.

Comment: There's no dynamic caching needed because it is assumed that index.html is a static file just like any png or jpg or pdf. So S3 is literally your cache. It's your CDN.

Comment: If I were to dynamically load contents (images/videos) from Amazon S3, is it possible to use static index.html? Could you tell me how Ebay or Airbnb allow the users to upload pics and manage to seperate client/server ??